# ggpairs: adjusting axis labels to show minimum and maximum only

Tags: r, axes, ggally

I want to show just the minimum and maximum values for all the axes of a `ggpairs {GGally}` plot. Find below a reproducible example

```
df=as.data.frame(matrix(1:1000,nrow = 100))
ggpairs(df)
```

[image]

I know I can do it individually by using `breaks`, but I don't know how can I apply this in `ggpairs`. Can somebody help me?

Comment: one way is to define your own function.... `my_fn <- function(data, mapping, ...){  ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping, ...) + ; geom_point(...) +    ; scale_y_continuous(breaks=round(range(data[,as.character(mapping$y)]))) +;
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=round(range(data[,as.character(mapping$x)])))
}` . Then plot `ggpairs(df, lower=list(continuous=my_fn))` . You can tweak the breaks to make more pretty values, change the density plot similarilty etc etc

Comment: It works. Thanks. If you post this as an answer I will accept it. I guess I have to do the same for diagonal plots to adjust the axes labels of top-left and bottom-right density plots as well?