# how to define facet axis limits in ggpairs function

Tags: r, plot, ggally, ggpairs

Having a `ggpairs` function, how would one limit range of lower facets to e.g. 0.5 for x and y?

```
library(GGally)

xy <- data.frame(matrix(runif(4 * 1000), ncol = 4))

ggpairs(xy)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define a function which plots (one facet). You can go wild with `ggplot` in here. See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764317/ggpairs-adjusting-axis-labels-to-show-minimum-and-maximum-only).

```
limitRange <- function(data, mapping, ...) { 
  ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping, ...) + 
    geom_point(...) + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.5)) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.5)) 
}

# This is how you specify which part of the image will be
# plotted using your function.
ggpairs(xy, lower = list(continuous = limitRange))
```

[image]